# Repeat VBA Code on rows with specific cells needed

Tags: excel, vba, loops, row

I am new to VBA coding and struggling to figure out a little loop problem.

I want to repeat code on multiple rows but using cell specific code that adds a new line to a new sheet. How do I loop the code but each time the code drops to the next line?

For example, I have a new sheet that I then concatenate A1, B1 and "text" from the first row of a data range on the first sheet. How would I get the code to essentially roll down a row when the code block is repeated ( A2, B2 and "text" )

I currently have the following:

[Copy data range into new workbook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIPha.png) ( Some parts marked out due to privacy, also its in a notepad as it was too big to screenshot directly from VBA ) ( this code works perfectly each time )

My Loop Code block looks like this:

[Loop Code Block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DivH2.png)

The above code block is the one that I would like to repeat to each line of a data range that I have on sheet one, onto the new sheet that has been created.

I've done hours of research online but struggling to make sense of examples found and or having issues trying to get them to work for mine.

Any help and advice would be massively appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Please update your question after checking https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, specifically the part about [Why not upload images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are wanting to repeat your code every 2 lines on the new sheet. Unless you are creating a new sheet for every iteration, you do not want your sheets.add within the loop. OW you will get a ton of new sheets.

The main thing is to not hardcode your values within the loop but to instead reference your loop counter within the loop:

Sub LoopExample()

```
Dim x As Integer
Dim NumRows As Integer

NumRows = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

For x = 1 To NumRows Step 2

    'directly reference your code in this area
    'instead of using select or activecell, type
    'out the worksheet name you are referencing
    'you can use a with statement if using the same
    'sheet/range repeatedly
    
    'in your range withn the loop, write
    'range("A" & x) for "A1"
    'range("A" &x+1) for "A2", etc
    
    'at the end of this loop, the step 3 will skip
    ' to row 3 in the next iteration which will repeat
    'your process there. I am assuming that every
    '2 lines you want to repeat this code since
    ' you input information for the first and second rows.
    
    'could also use an offset on each of your cells
    'to achieve the same thing without the step
        
Next x
```

End Sub

Hopefully I correctly interpreted your question and this is helpful!